# How to debug order of events in React component

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, reactjs, keyboard-events

I have the following React component in which I'm trying to re-implement my own syntax highlighting and autocomplete features to build a text editor*.

When I don't use the chrome debugger, both onInput and onKeydDown events fire, but when I place a debugger breakpoint on the onInput (which fires first), the onInput event appears to never fire. Why? And What can I do about it?

```
// Box containing my forula (which consists of text, transformed into many <span>s);
var SyntaxBox = React.createClass({

  //basically a custom eventing system
  _emitChangeEvent: function(){
    console.log('changeEvent'); // <-- this will always log. But if a place a chrome breakPoint here, and then step through, the onInput event is never fired.
    var node = this.refs.formulaEditor.getDOMNode();
    var formula = node.textContent; //this is the concat of just the content of all child elements. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent
    if(this.props.onChange && formula !== this.props.formula){
      this.props.onChange({
        target: {
          value: formula.replace(/\u00a0/g, " ") //strip out and replace &nbsp (unicode 00a0) with normal spaces
        } //this value gets sent to listeners in the parent component
      });
    }
  },

  _captureNavigation: function(event){
    console.log('keyDown'); // <-- this is always logged unless a breakpoint is placed in the console.log above in _emitChangeEvent. Why? And is there a workaround?
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <code
            onInput={this._emitChangeEvent}
            onKeyDown={this._captureNavigation}
            contentEditable
            ref='formulaEditor'
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.html}}>
          </code>
        </div>
      </div>
        );
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
    var formulaString = nextProps.formula;
    var formattedHTML = highlighter.colorise(formulaString); //external helper function that does syntax highlighting by taking a string and returning styles span tags
    this.setState({html: formattedHTML});
  }

});
```

*I haven't found a library yet that will give me control over both (1) which words to highlight and how I can style them, and (2) the UI and view of the auto-completing list of options and how they are selected.

Comment: If you add `debugger;` to the `_emitChangeEvent` function, does it stop on that line? Is there a source map for the file? Where is the JSX->Javascript taking place?

Comment: Yup. It'll stop as expected, but then when I hit 'play' to execute the remaining code, the second onKeyDown event is never fired. I can't imagine why... I'm using the [Gulp JSX -> JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-react) module with source mapping turned on, and that seems to be working fine.